# Store Textview from ArrayList

Tags: android, textview

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = database.query("remedies", new String[] { "remedy" },
            "d_id=?", new String[] { "" + index }, null, null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        al.add(c.getString(0));
    }
    c.close();

    TextView[] tv = new TextView[al.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        tv[i].setText(al.get(i));
    }
```

my logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ayurvedicapp/com.example.ayurvedichomecure.Remedies}:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Exception at: tv[i].setText(al.get(i));
```

Plz give me solution

Comment: What is you question, see [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tv[i].setText(al.get(i));` this cause Exception.

Because your TextView is null,

You have just declare an Array of TextView but you haven't really instantiate the textview's.

Try this

```
TextView[] tv = new TextView[al.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
       tv[i]=new TextView(context);
        tv[i].setText(al.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    tv[i] = new TextView(context); // Provide a proper context or if you plan to use findViewById
    tv[i].setText(al.get(i));
}
```

You've just declared your array of TextView, but have not initialized each in element in that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            tv[i] = new TextView(context);
            tv[i].setText(al.get(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
 TextView[] tv = new TextView[al.size()]; //Textviews of the arraylist size. array of textviews with 
 for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) { //loop to the size of the list
  tv[i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this); //new textview 
  tv[i].setText(al.get(i)); //set textview with the data from the list using index i
  }
```